# how get root access with docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

i used below config yml:

```
web:
image: nginx:latest
ports:
    - "8080:80"
volumes:
    - ./code:/code
    - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
```

why permissions error for access `/etc/nginx` or `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating crmapicoremain_web_1 ... 
Creating crmapicoremain_web_1 ... done
Attaching to crmapicoremain_web_1
web_1  | nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
web_1  | 2017/10/30 05:45:48 [emerg] 1#1: no port in upstream "php-fpm" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/CRM.conf:18
crmapicoremain_web_1 exited with code 1
```

how can access the root user with docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: you should stick to absolute path referencing for both side don't use relative referencing

Comment: @Hamuel Why? It can make sense to go with relative paths on your host, i.e. have your docker-compose.yml and needed config files in a git repository. clone, up, done; Furthermore that does not have anything to do with the question;

Comment: Do you have a full error message for us?

Comment: @tworabbits edited question!

Comment: What is your host operating system? is SELinux set to Enabled?

Comment: @FarhadFarahi yes!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to set `SELinux` to `Permissive/Disabled` and try again.

```
su -c "setenforce 0"
```

Please Note this will reduce your security and not recommended in production environments, You should try to fix the issue and enable SELinux.

Comment: thanks alot!
can you help me about set permission without turn off SElinux?

Comment: There is a good read https://medium.com/lucjuggery/docker-selinux-30-000-foot-view-30f6ef7f621